# Microsoft Graph API - Update Existing Group

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update the description for an existing group in Azure AD, but I'm getting an error message that I'm not sure how to resolve.

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateGroup(GraphServiceClient graphClient, Group group)
{
    // Update the group.
    Group grp = await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Request().GetAsync();
    grp.Description = group.Description;

    await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(grp);

    return true;
}
```

The above just throws an exception:

> Code: BadRequest Message: Operation not supported.

I'm not sure if this is a lack of enabled permissions for the API in Azure or if updating a group genuinely isn't supported?
I can Create/Delete groups easily enough, so surely updating an existing group should be just as easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're first populating `grp`, changing a single property, and then attempting to `PATCH` the *entire* Group object. So along with your updated description, you're also attempting to `PATCH` (and this is where the error comes from) several *read-only* properties (e.g. `id`).

Your code should look like this:

```
await graphClient
    .Groups[group.Id]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(new Group() {
        Description = group.Description
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, that worked perfectly! I assumed it would just work out what to do but actually your explanation makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

The update operation for group is supported in Graph API.[image]

I don't have VS env in personal PC, so I cannot test the Graph Library now(I can test it on Oct 2th). If Graph Libray have supported the API too, the code should works well, so you can check your permission config first.

```
await graphClient.Groups[group.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(grp);
```

Some reference from Graph Library code:

> ```
> /// <summary>
>  /// Updates the specified Group using PATCH.
>  /// </summary>
>  /// <param name="groupToUpdate">The Group to update.</param>
>  /// <returns>The updated Group.</returns>
>   public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Group> UpdateAsync(Group groupToUpdate)
>    {
>    }
>
>
>
>
>    /// <summary>
>     /// Updates the specified Group using PATCH.
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="groupToUpdate">The Group to update.</param>
>     /// <param name="cancellationToken">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> for the request.</param>
>     /// <returns>The updated Group.</returns>
>     public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Group> UpdateAsync(Group groupToUpdate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     {
>
>     }
> ```
>
> https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/f807196101e20d30fbc8628206a2eb5850334a92/src/Microsoft.Graph/Requests/Generated/GroupRequest.cs

Comment: My application has got Group.ReadWrite.All selected as both an application permission and a delegated permission.
I'm using the examples given here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/GroupsService.cs

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to [@Marc LaFleur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur) above. The package version I am using differs; the code that worked for me is slightly different without the `.Request()` and `UpdateAsync()` methods.

```
        await _graphServiceClient.Groups[ActiveDirectoryGroupObjectId]
            .PatchAsync(new Group()
            {
                DisplayName = "Updated Name",
                Description = "Updated Description"
                // Additional properties...
            });
```